# Not showing data in HTML from Angular app

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm consuming a Django REST API with an Angular JS app. I want to print a list of classrooms in a HTML table. This is the Json data I get from the REST API: http://pastebin.com/raw/s0knYX89

Here's the HTML

```
<div ng-app="userListApp">
    <div ng-controller="UsersController">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Classroom</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>Academic year</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="classroom in classrooms">
                  <td>{{classroom.classroom}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.school.school_name}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.academic_year}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the app.js

```
var userListApp = angular.module('userListApp', ['ngResource']);

userListApp.factory('Classroom', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/classrooms/?format=json', {}, {
          query: {
              method: 'GET',
              isArray:true,
            }
        });
    });


userListApp.controller('UsersController', function($scope, $resource, Classroom) {
  Classroom.query({},function(data) {
      $scope.classrooms = data;
      console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Anyway, all I get is this

[image]

I put `console.log(data);` to check if the data arrives to the page, and that's what I get: all of the data in the console, and none in the HTML page - even though the rows of the table are three, exactly the number I should get, but they are all blank.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of trying to print that right away. Use Promise's `then` method for defining a callback for async tasks, such as consulting a service

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `console.log`, the data returned is a promise. Try to access the `api` response correctly.

Comment: I found this `Note: In contrast to $http.config, promises are not supported in $resource, because the same value would be used for multiple requests. If you are looking for a way to cancel requests, you should use the cancellable option.` in Angular documentation.  
What should I do, then?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ng-show` on the `table`:

```
<table ng-show = "classrooms != null" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Classroom</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>Academic year</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="classroom in classrooms">
                  <td>{{classroom.classroom}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.school.school_name}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.academic_year}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Where did you `call` a functnio to start `$http` request?

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working with ng-show. What do you mean with your question? Anyway I'm using "$resource", not "$http".

Comment: In your controller you need to start Classroom.query, how do you do it?

Comment: Uhm, the script I copy-pasted in the original question is everything I have (I don't know if this answers to your question, I'm new to Angular JS and I'm trying to understand some concepts!)

Comment: Could the "$resource" url be the problem? Like, writing it like I did, with the "?format=json" at the end?